# pexpect, script time out when expecting '$'

Tags: python, pexpect, spawn

I am learning python using pexpect command, I am trying to write a script usign ssh to multiple servers and run remote installation, however when the script run to child.expect('$') it timeout and did not carry out subsequent tasks, can see what might be wrong?

here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pexpect
import getpass
import pdb

user = raw_input("what is username:")
paswd =getpass.getpass("Please enter your password: ")
seNam = raw_input("Server name:")

child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o PreferredAuthentications=\"password\" "' + user + "@" + seNam)
child.logfile = sys.stdout
child.expect('password:')
child.sendline(paswd)
child.expect('$')
child.sendline("ls -l")
child.expect('$')
child.sendline("exit")

raw_input("please press enter to continue...")
```

And here is the error messgag i got from pdb

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "./expecTest.py", line 23, in <module>
child.expect('$')

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect.py", line 1311, in expect
return self.expect_list(compiled_pattern_list, timeout, searchwindowsize)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect.py", line 1325, in expect_list
return self.expect_loop(searcher_re(pattern_list), timeout, searchwindowsize)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect.py", line 1409, in expect_loop
raise TIMEOUT (str(e) + '\n' + str(self))
```

pexpect.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().

Thanks!

Comment: What does your logfile look like

Comment: try `child.expect_exact('$')` or `child.expect(r'\$')`.

Comment: Thanks for that, it worked with `child.expect(r'\$')`

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue myself and the comment by @jfs saved me much time of debugging.

The issue is the call to `child.expect('$')`.  Because pexpect uses regex matching by default, and because `$` is the "end of line" metacharacter in regex, it's expecting to find the end of line right there instead of a literal `$`.

The solution is to escape the symbol: `\$`, or use `child.expect_exact('$')` which matches the string literal instead of a regular expression.

Note: If @jfs posts an answer I'm happy to take mine down so they get all the credit.